# $\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis, find all the vectors $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\langle v, v_1+v_2-v_3\rangle=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$\mathcal{B}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is an orthonormal basis, find all the vectors $v\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\langle v, v_1+v_2-v_3\rangle=0$.

I've done the following: I've expanded $$\langle v, v_1+v_2-v_3\rangle=0$$

using the linearity property

$$\langle v,v_1\rangle+\langle v,v_2\rangle+\langle v,-v_3\rangle=0$$

I know that there are the vectors $v_{n\in\{1,2,3\}}=\{(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$, but I guess that there are other vectors that suffice the conditions, the given basis is required to be orthonormal, then it should consist of unit vectors such that $|v_n|=1$. How do I find all the other vectors such that $|v_n|=1$?

From here I have no clue on how to proceed, I know that perhaps there may be a way to do it via parametrization. I've done some probing and I'm thinking that there are a lot of values that could do it, but I'm unable to think of a way to do it.

Comment: I think the question asks you to find a basis for the orthogonal complement of $\operatorname{span}(v_1+v_2-v_3)$, i.e. you need to find a basis of the subspace that consists of all vectors orthogonal to $v_1+v_2-v_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you're looking for other vectors with norm $1$; there are infinitely many such vectors, and there are a *lot* of choices for an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (in fact, unless the inner product is explicitly specified, it's not guaranteed that $(1, 0, 0)$ is a unit vector with respect to $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$).

---

Here's a way to proceed in a fairly simple manner: Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, write $$v = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3$$

Convince yourself, after using the linearity of $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and orthonormality of the basis that

$$\langle v, v_1 + v_2 - v_3\rangle = 0 \iff c_1 + c_2 - c_3 = 0$$

To see this, use linearity in *both* of the two coordinates, and pull the constants $c_i$ outside of the inner product.

Comment: How does this address the OP's question "How do I find all the other vectors such that $|v_n|=1$?"

Comment: @FlybyNight I've edited my answer to hopefully address that; I don't see immediately how it's useful to try finding vectors with norm $1$ here.

Comment: I don't see how it's useful either. What is useful is to address the OP :)

Comment: @FlybyNight Yes. He's right. Some time later I realized that it's useless to find all the unit vectors.

Comment: @T.Bongers The orthonormality of the basis means that the sum of all vectors in the basis equals $1$, right? I've thought only this by summing $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ as an example.

Comment: @IgäriaMnagarka No, it means that every vector in the basis has length $1$, in the sense that $$\sqrt{\langle v_i, v_i \rangle} = 1$$

Comment: @T.Bongers Yes, but there could be also unit vectors that are not perpendicular to each other, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, which is why orthogonality is important here. So we have $\langle v_i, v_i \rangle = 1$ and $\langle v_i, v_j\rangle = 0$ if $i \ne j$.

Comment: @T.Bongers I'm still stuck. I've written $\langle v,v_1 \rangle+\langle v,v_2 \rangle + \langle v,v_3 \rangle=0$ but I still can't see it.

Comment: Write $v = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3$ and expand *everything* completely; after simplifying, can you justify why it becomes $$c_1 \langle v_1, v_1 \rangle + c_2 \langle v_2, v_2 \rangle - c_3 \langle v_3, v_3 \rangle = 0 ?$$

Comment: @T.Bongers I don't understand where are you taking the $c_n$'s from. I'm thinking like this: $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, $v_1=(v_{1,1},v_{1,2},v_{1,3})$, $v_2=(v_{2,1},v_{2,2},v_{2,3})$, $v_3=(v_{3,1},v_{3,2},v_{3,3})$.

Comment: The $c_n$s are described in my answer: Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, we can write $v$ as a linear combination of the basis vectors.

Comment: @T.Bongers Any orthonormal basis is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$? I'm still a little confused because I've read a little about subspaces and there are subspaces that are different of the primary vector space.

Comment: @IgäriaMnagarka I think you're confused about what my solution is trying to do; here is an outline: 1. Write down *any* orthonormal basis $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. 2. Write down *any* vector $v$, and put it in terms of the basis as $$v = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3$$ Here, we use that $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis. 3. Compute $\langle v, v_1 + v_2 - v_3\rangle$ using the orthonormality of the basis to simplify $\langle v_i, v_j\rangle$; the result is $c_1 + c_2 - c_3$. 4. Set that to $0$, showing that the characterization is $c_1 + c_2 - c_3 = 0$.

Comment: @T.Bongers I guess I got it. $h$ is the vector $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$. Then I multiply each of it's coordinates for one vector of the basis in order to obtain $v$ which is: $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$?

Comment: @IgäriaMnagarka Where did $h$ come from? $v$ is a *given* vector, and then we can find constants $c_n$ to write the equation $v = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + c_3 v_3$.

Comment: @T.Bongers $h$ is just an aribtrary name for the vector. When I used it, I was trying to refer to $v$, to avoid confusion with the $v_n$'s.